# Redirection Issue in My wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, redirect

Below is the link to sites problem page

http://tpwp.staging.wpengine.com/marketcoding/

In these posts when I open a link using 'open in new tab' options, the links are perfectly good but when I open it just by clicking the link redirecting me the same page. 
what can the issue?

Comment: Questions must include the relevant code, not just links to other sites.

Comment: I can upload 1000 lines of code but is that makes any sense? if you know how to solve, you better provide it and honestly, i am only giving my staging server link, so you know I am not looking for traffic or anything. if you are downvoting something think twice from next time.

Comment: Rather than arguing, have a look at the guidelines for this network. Your question is in violation. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I've checked and found the problem. You need to remove/comment this code: "a.preventDefault();"

```
jQuery(document).on("click","article.et_pb_post .entry-title a",function(a){a.preventDefault();
```

You may test as I did:

1- save your home page on desktop.

2- Edit that page in notepad++

3- Press ctrl+f

4- search this code line below:

```
jQuery(document).on("click","article.et_pb_post .entry-title a",function(a){a.preventDefault();
```

add two slashes before "a.preventDefault()" to comment so it should like this:
"//a.preventDefault();"

5- Save and launch this file on browser and then check

In my test It's working once I comment this line, to update this on your wordpress try to find this code in your wordpress files.

Comment: it's loading on the current page, can you help me with the 'new tab'?

Comment: add target="_blank" in anchor or you may call these lines in the same place where you commented the //a.preventDefault(); code.     var url = $(this).attr('href'); 
    window.open(url, '_blank'); join me at skype: wendy.disney

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Couldn't up vote your answer, as i am new. Thank you.